# How to force TLS 1.2 usage for PhpMailer 5.2

Tags: phpmailer

Recently the 3rd party email service provider I was using made a change. They disabled support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.

I provide support for an ancient system that still uses php 5.3 and phpmailer 5.2.

My tests indicates that TLS 1.2 is enabled.

But, the PHPMailer code cannot connect to the email server after the disabling of TLS 1.0 and 1.1

Also, note that I am not a full time php expert.

Is there a way to make PHPMailer 5.2 use tls 1.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not up to PHPMailer, its up to the version of PHP that you're using to run it, so the solution is to update your PHP version. The major changes relating to TLS were largely in PHP 5.6, so upgrading to that would be a good intermediate point if you're really stuck with this legacy version.

Comment: That is the best explanation that I have heard. I will accept your answer as soon as it allows me. Thanks!

Comment: Upgrading from 5.4 to 5.6 solved my problem when Office365 stopped supporting v1.0 and v1.1

Comment: Based on my experience, this answer is partially incorrect. PHP 5.6 adds ssl/tls version selection, but older versions of PHPMailer will still use tls v1.0 until you either hack it (as reported in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70408081/410761) or update it and configure it to use the new protocol version.

Comment: Not true. If you look at PHPMailer's code (even [in an old version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/5.2-stable/class.smtp.php#L359)), you'll find it works around that issue by explicitly adding back support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 for the PHP versions that removed it (5.6.7). This code was added in 2016. If you do what the other answer suggests instead of this cleaner approach, your connections will not work for servers that only support TLS 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: Sometimes updating the version of PHP is not an immediately available option, and generally, if you're having an issue like this it's on a specific server with a specific version of the OS, etc, in which case hard coding PHPMailer to use 1.2 if it's available in your build of PHP is fine.  Of course the best thing to do is to update the OS/Apache/PHP, but again that's not always an option that can be executed immediately.

Answer (score 29):

Look for constant STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT in file class.smtp.php and update that to STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
Like this:

```
public function startTLS()
{
    if (!$this->sendCommand('STARTTLS', 'STARTTLS', 220)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Begin encrypted connection
    if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto(
        $this->smtp_conn,
        true,
        STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
    )) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You should run phpinfo() in a small php script on your server to make sure TLS 1.2 is available in the first place.

Comment: I was already at PHP 5.6 but it still didn't work. I imagine I needed to set some defaults in the Windows server but this was way easier. Thanks for the answer...

Comment: This worked perfecrly for my legacy app, many thanks.

Comment: These one worked for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me with PHP 5.6, my email account fixed was one of godaddy

Comment: This one worked for me when fixing a Perch 2 shop instance. If it hadn't, I'd have been very much out of other options! Cheers Nick!

Comment: This worked for Laravel 5.2 (SwiftMailer) - file in question is `/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php`