# TLS error when sending email using PHPmailer on IIS server

Tags: php, iis, phpmailer, iis-10

I have moved a custom PHP web app from one old windows server to a new one.

Everything is working except the email feature which uses PHPmailer. This feature works in my test environment, which is XAMPP, but produces errors when using IIS.

I am sending email through office365 (smtp.office365.com) which I can't change.

I have enabled SSL in the php.ini file:
`extension=php_openssl.dll`

This is the code I have to set up the message:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
//Configure the mail server
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "email@address.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
//Allow connections to unverified certificates (self signed certificates), due to org policy
$mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true));
```

This produces the following output:

```
debug level 3; message: Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ), )debug level 3; message: Connection: openeddebug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 SYBPR01CA0060.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 9 Feb 2022 23:16:25 +0000 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO SERVERNAME debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SYBPR01CA0060.outlook.office365.com Hello [IP] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready debug level 1; message: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO eqgbn5534012 debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SYBPR01CA0060.outlook.office365.com Hello [IP] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [SYBPR01CA0060.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com] debug level 1;
 message: SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [SYBPR01CA0060.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com] debug level 3;
 message: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT debug level 2; message: SERVER -> CLIENT: debug level 1;
 message: SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: debug level 3;
 message: Connection: closeddebug level 3;
 message: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Which seems to indicate that it's an issue with the version of TLS which is used by PHPmailer, however this exact same code works on my test server (through the same host with the same username and password). This leads me to think that it's some sort of configuration issue with IIS.

I did try to force PHPMailer to use a newer version of TLS, based on this SO question:

[How to force TLS 1.2 usage for PhpMailer 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873422/how-to-force-tls-1-2-usage-for-phpmailer-5-2)

But this just lead to another SMTP error:

```
debug level 3; message: Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ), )debug level 3;
 message: Connection: openeddebug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 SYBPR01CA0174.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 9 Feb 2022 06:47:55 +0000 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO SERVERNAME debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SYBPR01CA0174.outlook.office365.com Hello [IP] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: IP SMTP server ready debug level 3;
 message: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.debug level 1;
 message: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT debug level 2;
 message: SERVER -> CLIENT: debug level 1;
 message: SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: debug level 3;
 message: Connection: closeddebug level 3;
 message: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

My question is, is there a setting in IIS which could be impacting which TLS version is used by PHPmailer?

Comment: What is your Windows Server (and  .NET Framework) version ??

Comment: Windows Server 2016. In IIS manager, the .NET version is 2.0 in the application pool.

Comment: I should also add that I am using PHP 5.5.6.

Comment: If I remember correctly .NET 4.6.2 (or above) is required for TLS 1.2 (which is now required for office 365 connection)

Comment: According to my registry on the server, it's actually .NET 4.8 (sorry, not super familiar with MS Server).

Comment: OK, then your server should support tls 1.2, but for your PHP, I am doubtful whether 5.5.6 (which you are using) can work. First of all, please change STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT in file class.smtp.php and update that to STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT For details, please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873422/how-to-force-tls-1-2-usage-for-phpmailer-5-2) , make sure after you made the change you restart the machine. Secondly, if it still fails, then please upgrade your PHP version to PHP 5.6 because this is 5.6 which have major changes implemented on TLS

Comment: PHP 5.5 is very old and hasn't gotten any updates (even security updates) since 2016! If this app is exposed online, then you have some security issues. The oldest supported version right now is PHP 7.4. It might be time to upgrade and fix any incompatibilities you might have.

Comment: All of this is really pretty irresponsible. You are deliberately lowering safeguards and exposing your server to attack. I don't buy disabling certificate verification as a policy; it's Microsoft's servers you're connecting to, not your own, and if you can't verify them, it's because your server's config is broken, most likely due to outdated CA certs, *not* because MS is using self-signed certs (because they're not).

Comment: It's an internally facing server/app only used by a small team. Security on the server is not a worry at this point. As to why the server uses self-signed certificates, this is part of a much larger organisation and I'm not sure about the nuance of the policy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the version of PHP. As M. Eriksson stated, this version was too old for the newer version of TLS.

I have upgraded to a newer version and this fixed the issue.